# More control when doing animations in Dashcode/Dashboard?

Tags: javascript, widget, dashboard, dashcode

Recently I am giving another shot to Dashcode ;)

It's great. Is just I think is not well documented.
I have a stackLayout object with only two views in it, and a couple of buttons that interchange the views with a transition.(views show data of a large array, `list`)
Animations and transitions work perfect. The problem is, when I press a button while animating the animation starts again and it looks ugly (If I had n views for a datasource array of length n this should't be a problem, but this is not my case).

I want to disable buttons while animation is taking place.

Is there any callback, delegate, or any way I can get a notification when the animation is finished?

This is what I have done:

```
function _changeView(transitionDirection, newIndex){

    //Create transition
    var newTransition = new Transition(Transition.SWAP_TYPE, 0.9, Transition.EASE_TIMING);
    newTransition.direction = transitionDirection;

    //I only have two views. I use currentView's id to calculate not current view id and change text inside of it. 
    var stackLayout = document.getElementById('stackLayout').object;//stackLayout object
    var nextViewId = (stackLayout.getCurrentView().id == 'view1')? '2':'1'; //

    //change the text in the view that is going to appear   
    document.getElementById('text'+nextViewId).innerHTML = list[curIndex];

    stackLayout.setCurrentViewWithTransition('view'+ nextViewId, newTransition, false);
}

function goPrevious(event)
{
    curIndex--;
    if(curIndex < 0){ 
        curIndex = list.length-1;
    }
    _changeView(Transition.LEFT_TO_RIGHT_DIRECTION, curIndex);
}

function goNext(event)
{
    curIndex++;
    if(curIndex >list.length - 1){ 
        curIndex = 0;
    }
    _changeView(Transition.RIGHT_TO_LEFT_DIRECTION, curIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually found the answer to this. Here's how I did it:

```
document.getElementById('stackLayout').object.endTransitionCallback=function(stackLayout, oldView, newView) {
    //PUT CODE HERE USING stackLayout, oldView, newView to show params
}
```

In fact you can find all the stackLayout methods and properties in the StackLayout.js file in your project!!

Hope this helps